# Update item from foreach every 10.5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

So I have this code:

```
$.getJSON( "fetch-beacons.php", function( beacons ) {
beacons.forEach(function(beacon) {
    if (beacon.uid != "<?php echo $uid ?>"){
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            strokeColor: '#add8e6',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            fillColor: '#add8e6',
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map: map,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(Number(beacon.lat), Number(beacon.lng)),
            radius: Number(beacon.radius)
        });
        circle.addListener('click', function() {
            post('claimcreds.php', {id: beacon.id, cid: <?php echo $uid ?>, uid: beacon.uid, lat: pos.lat, lng: pos.lng, claimattempt: "true"});
            });
            }
    else {
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: '#ffa500',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        fillColor: '#ffa500',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(Number(beacon.lat), Number(beacon.lng)),
        radius: Number(beacon.radius)
          });
         }
      });
    });
```

It's fetching details about some circles from a JSON document, and it works fine. The problem is, I want to check the circle position against another position (let's call it `pos`) every 10 seconds, to see whether `pos` is inside the circle.

As I understand it, the way to do this is `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(circle.center, pos);` and then see if the radius is more or less than that, however I'm not sure how I'd do that every ten seconds, given that the circle variables aren't saved as they are looped through by the `beacons.forEach` statement.

Can anyone help? Sorry if what I'm asking isn't clear/if the code's a bit messy hehe :)

Comment: You'll have to start with saving whatever you want to compare against, and then creating the functionality for comparing, and once that is done, you just stick it in an `setInterval`

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question; keep a cache of the data you want to check, then recursive `setTimeout` loop to perform your test every x milliseconds

Comment: @PaulS. @adeno How would I do that without overwriting the variable though? Sorry, I'm new to JS :/ Could I do something like (pseudocode) `$i  = 0; $circle.$i = xyz; $i++;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would do something like this.  Firstly define a global function like:

```
function checkDistance(circle) { 
    var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(circle.getCenter(), pos);

    if (distance > x) {
        alert('ok');
    }
}
```

It takes one parameter, `circle`.  I'm assuming `pos` is a global variable it can access.

Then inside your forEach loop, after your if-else statement (assuming you want to apply it to both kinds of circle), call that function on a 10.5 second interval.  It uses the `circle` variable you've just created as a parameter you pass to the function:

```
setInterval(checkDistance, 10500, circle);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, and it seems to have worked, but it stops my geolocation from working :( not sure why...

http://pastebin.com/urkYPvKG is my geolocation code.

Comment: Because you have a syntax error in your code. Run it through http://jshint.com/ to see the problem - an unclosed `{`. You've not closed the `forEach` or the `getJSON` callback

Comment: Run it through said site, fixed the errors I could see, but it's still not working :( http://pastebin.com/s7mHRwdM

Comment: Because you've still got syntax errors. Line 72, you've got `}}` when it should be `})`

Comment: Hmm, that's odd... Why aren't all these errors showing in any of my JavaScript consoles? (I've run the code through Edge, Firefox default and Firefox Firebug)

Comment: Fixed that. Put it through JSFiddle, not seeing any errors. Put it through JSLint, it's yelling at me for "unexpected var" for this code: http://pastebin.com/e2R7tGGW But the code runs fine in the browser, except for the fact that the geolocation still won't happen! Aargh this is frustrating.